# Stagefright vs Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, stagefright

What are the advantages of using gstreamer over stagefright? Could anyone please point out the difference.

Comment: @Ruchi.. I have tried to answer your question. Please comment if you were looking for something more specific as the question is a bit open-ended.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On the onset, one very generic comment. It is very debatable if `GStreamer` is advantageous over `Stagefright` or not. However, some points to answer your question are as below.

`Stagefright` relies only on `OMX` / `OpenMax` interface for all the codecs, whereas `GStreamer` codec plugin can be written over `non-OMX` interfaces. For example, even *software codecs* are encapsulated into `SoftOMXComponent` in `Stagefright` framework, whereas the same can easily be converted into a `GstElement` without necessarily having a `OMX` interface.

In `Stagefright`, the communication interface between 2 components is very generic and typically is `MediaBuffer`. This is not a `hard` binding, but more facilitated through the **Glue Layer** i.e. implementation of the `OMXCodec` or `MediaExtractor` or `AwesomePlayer`.

In `GStreamer`, the typical communication interface is through the `Pads` which have specific `GstCaps`. Two components' pads are inter-linked through `gst_pad_link`.

`GStreamer` provides standard template `bins` like `CameraBin` or `PlayerBin` whereas in `Stagefright` you have a `cameraHal` implementation for `camera`. For players, there are 2 potential player engine implementations like `StagefrightPlayer` or `NuPlayer`.

In `Stagefright`, data processing is driven by the `sink` (downstream) **PULL**-ing data from the `source`. In `GStreamer`, the data processing can potentially be triggered by the `source` creating the buffer and **PUSH**-ing it to downstream (Reference: [here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/chapter-data.html#section-buffers)).

A last point, `Gstreamer` is widely deployed as compared to `Stagefright` which is currently android specific.

While the list can continue, there are a lot of **similarities** between the 2 frameworks. For example,

1. Both frameworks create the components like `parsers` or `codecs` through `Factory Methods` i.e. they employ a `Factory` pattern.
2. Both frameworks employ a `plugin` interface to integrate newer components like for example `parsers`.

Comment: Great answer. Here's my personal view:
i) GStreamer is very similar to the deprecated Microsoft DirectShow filters, I'm not sure whose influencing who; ii) Stagefright is moving towards an asynchronous model (ACodec replacing OMXCodec; ALooper and AHandler are easy to use libraries); iii) GStreamer is more mature and general in its problem statement, Stagefright's goal is to solve Android's playback and there are vendor-specific quirks buried in different libstagefright.so.

Comment: @leesei.. I have a slightly different view on the last part.. `Stagefright` is becoming far more generic with all building blocks becoming visible at the `Java` layer. Though not as feature rich as `GStreamer`, it is ensuring an increasing reach of underlying HW capabilities to end user. Hence, the framework is far more generic than to solve only the playback problem. I would love to hear your view on this topic.

Comment: @Ganesh Thanks for pointing that out, I agree that `Stagefright` could be more generic. I missed the recording part totally. My focus was `Stagefright` being limited to Android and not the limitation of  `Stagefright` itself. We can write generic player, recorder, trancoders, post-processors from the abstracted Extractor/Codec/Writer/Render (they are pretty good). I would like to have them outside of Android, sadly `Stagefright` at its current state is deeply entrenched with the platform (AOSP) source code (e.g.: platform headers, Android Native Buffer and quirks of OMX codecs).

Comment: @leesei.. precisely in the point you have rightly highlighted, `GStreamer` scores over the `Android` `Stagefright` as it has the building blocks as standard `API`s and is far more widely adopted in the `linux` community. Thanks for the great discussion !!

Comment: Yes, having worked with both DirectShow and GStreamer, they are extremely similar in terms of being streaming media graph systems.  It's worth noting, however, that neither is the first example of such a system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with StageFright, but I would point out that GStreamer offers some very mature debugging capabilities, including dumping GraphViz ("dot") data that can be used to construct literal, visual graphs of your figurative playback graphs, including during construction, even after certain kinds of partial failure.  Multiple debug levels are available, along with certain kinds of filtering.

I would definitely recommend anyone choosing between these two libraries for development purposes compare their debugging and troubleshooting capabilities, especially with respect to troubleshooting pipeline starvation and synchronization.

(Oh, and by the way-- the best format to convert those dot dumps to is SVG.  I usually open them in Firefox.)